# Minimal one line self introduction containing name and role/job/title

Tags: punctuation, commas

would it be correct to separate this with a comma? Or is there other punctuation which is more suitable like a colon?

> I'm neildaemond, an engineer in training.

or

> I'm neildeamond: an engineer in training.

or

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a comma is the correct way. It creates an appositive out of *an engineer in training* which is being attributed to *neildaemond*, so *neildaemond* is now also known as *an engineer in training*.

Using a colon here is technically also correct, but it shouldn't be used in a very short introduction like this. The colon simply says "What comes after me **is** what comes before me." So *an engineer in training* **is** *neildaemond*.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I found it very helpful.